# Why is this element not positioned at the bottom?

Tags: css, positioning, css-position

I do not understand why a `<footer>` element in my code is not located at the very bottom of it's page.

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kd5Xx/

I've set the position of both the footer and its parent, and i also gave it a specific height. HTML and body are set to height: 100%.

So why does this not work?

Comment: Because it's positioned `relative`. Use `absolute` instead.

Comment: When I tried your jsfiddle example, the footer was the only thing you defined. When I put other body text in above the footer, the footer showed up on the bottom as expected.

Comment: @mbratch
Could you provide a fiddle for me? I can't reproduce that, the footer will always just stay under the rest of the content, not exactly at the bottom of the page

Comment: @Vucko

See http://goo.gl/J94Pe

Comment: Ah.... sorry I missed the subtly of the "very bottom" which you indicated. In that case, caramba has the answer: use `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;`. You may have to pad the bottom of your content to avoid the last bit from truncation. I don't think you can have this both ways. Either you make the footer follow the bottom of the content and not be at the very bottom on short content, or you have to pad your content at the bottom. Or use javascript (a bit overkill).

Answer (score 0):

you have to make position:absolute; http://jsfiddle.net/Kd5Xx/1/

```
footer {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this would cause problems if the dynamic content on the page exceeds 100% of pageheight.
fixed positioning is maybe a solution, but then again i'd have to opush up the elements above

Comment: @user2422960  have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/Kd5Xx/6/ there are no changes in the css just ond div arround the "lorem ipsum" not what you want?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I forgot to mention that the footer should be alyways at the bottom, even in the case when the content above is less than 100% of the body-height

I tried this case with your fiddle and it worked, but i just can't get it to work here at my project. Has to be another issue, thank you very much for your efforts

Comment: @user2422960, give us a link if you've got it online